# Uso de mayusculas en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero que si x nombre se use en el prompt que en el texto indicado de la consola se ponga en mayuscula, se me pone arriba de todo y no en el texto, alguien sabe como arreglar esto?

```
let nombre = prompt("como te llamas bro?");
let edad = parseInt(prompt("decime tu edad pa"));

if  (nombre==="oscar"){
    console.log(nombre.toUpperCase());
}


console.log(`te llamas ${nombre}, tenes ${edad} años y el año que viene cumplis ${edad + 1}`);
```

Comment: No termino de entender la duda, ¿puedes explicar mejor?

Comment: Por ejemplo en el caso de que yo ponga Fabian en el prompt me aparezca en el texto de la consola normal, pero si pongo Oscar que me aparezca en mayuscula. Ejemplo de lo que quiero que me aparezca si pongo Oscar.te llamas OSCAR, tenes 45 años y el año que viene cumplis 46

Comment: Estás enviando el nombre en mayúsculas a la consola en lugar de convertirlo: `nombre = nombre.toUpperCase();`

Comment: Gracias triby ya esta solucionado

Comment: @SaantyCode sería muy muy útil si nos cuentas en una respuesta, la solución a tu pregunta. De paso, puedes marcar esa respuesta como aceptada para que todos los demás sepan cómo lo resolviste

Answer (score 0):

1.- El error es que cuando realizas la validacion solo muestras por consola, deberias de asignarle el valor mayuscula al la variable `nombre` quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
if (nombre === "oscar") {
  nombre = nombre.toUpperCase();
}
```

2.- De esta forma `nombre` solo se covertira a mayusculas si el valor es `oscar`

3.- ¿Te has preguntado que pasa si el usuario ingresa su nombre en mayusculas?

4.- Tendrias que controlar eso

```js
let nombre = prompt("como te llamas bro?").toLowerCase();
let edad = parseInt(prompt("decime tu edad pa"));

if (nombre === "oscar") {
  nombre = nombre.toUpperCase();
}

console.log(
  `te llamas ${nombre}, tenes ${edad} años y el año que viene cumplis ${
    edad + 1
  }`
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que de esta manera, te funcionaría perfectamente.

```
let nombre = prompt("como te llamas bro?");
let edad = parseInt(prompt("decime tu edad pa"));

if  (nombre === "oscar"){
     nombre = nombre.toUpperCase();
}


console.log(`te llamas ${nombre}, tenes ${edad} años y el año que viene cumplis ${edad + 1}`);
```